# How to create p:tabView with progressbar

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to create `p:tabView` with progressbar. Something like `p:tabMenu` - when tab is pressed the label of the tab is changed to `Loading` I would like to create something similar but with `p:tabView`. For example how I can call progressbar like [this](http://www.ajaxload.info/) and sop it when the loading is finished. Is there any possible way?

```
<p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="false">
    <p:tab id="tab1" title="tab1" >
        <ui:include src="tab1.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tab2" title="tab2" >
        <ui:include src="tab2.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="ta3" title="tab3" >
        <ui:include src="tab3.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tab4" title="tab4" >
        <ui:include src="tab4.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

One other option that may work will be to disable the tab label during the loading time.

Answer (score 3):

No need to disable anything yourself. Use primefaces [BlockUI](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/blockUI.jsf) to temporarily disable your tab. Simply add the following markup to your page:

```
  <p:blockUI block="myTabPanel" trigger="tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4" />
```

where `myTabPanel` is an `id` you will assign to your `<p:tabPanel/>`. See other usages for the blockUi component on the pf [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/blockUI.jsf)